# How to customise rEFInd theme on High Sierra?

Tags: macos, efi, themes

Installed rEFInd using the install binary. All working but the originally theme was a little uninspiring. So I followed following steps from this link.

> From OSX, do the following
>
> Start by mounting your EFI partition.
>
> sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes
>
> Then cd to the rEFInd directory on that partition cd
>   /Volumes/EFI/rEFInd
>
> Download the theme with Git
>
> git clone https://github.com/EvanPurkhiser/rEFInd-minimal
>
> Now add the theme info to refind.conf
>
> echo "include rEFInd-minimal/theme.conf" >> refind.conf
>
> Reboot with sudo reboot

everything seemed to execute successfuly and the line include rEFInd-minimal/theme.conf has been added to the refind.conf file but when I reboot the theme remains the same (original). Can it be customised?

Sorry, I'm pretty newbie when it comes to this stuff so go easy on me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but isn't

```
echo "include rEFInd-minimal/theme.conf" >> refind.conf
```

suppose to be the following.

```
echo "include themes/rEFInd-minimal/theme.conf" >> refind.conf
```

You omitted the `themes` folder, but there are many references to a `themes` folder in the `theme.conf` file.

I would suggest the following.

> From OSX, do the following
>
> Start by mounting your EFI partition.
>
> sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes
>
> Then cd to the rEFInd directory on that partition cd
>   /Volumes/EFI/rEFInd
>
> mkdir themes
>
> cd themes
>
> Download the theme with Git
>
> git clone https://github.com/EvanPurkhiser/rEFInd-minimal
>
> Now add the theme info to refind.conf
>
> cd ..
>   echo "include themes/rEFInd-minimal/theme.conf" >> refind.conf
>
> Reboot with sudo reboot

Comment: Thanks, that worked, however, now I have several OS's showing that are somewhat ruining the neatness. There are two Mac OS's, one blurry time machine icon, a legacy OS icon and a windows icon. I've been unsuccessfull in trying to find the efi files for the time machine/extra mac/legacy OS icons, and so have been unable to blacklist them in rEFInd, are you able to shed any light?

Comment: By default, rEFInd searches the internal drives for bootable operating systems. An experienced user will turn this feature off and manual enter the desired operating systems in to the `refind.conf` file. This also causes the rEFInd menu to appear sooner. Editing the `refind.conf` file might make a good subject for a new question.

Comment: Thanks David, after some more searching I finally understood how it works and got it looking pretty swish. It's surprisingly simple once you get the hang of the coding required.

Comment: I see you are new to Ask Different. It would be help others by marking your answer as having a solution. This can be done by accepting an answer. You can accept someones answer or post your own and and later accept your own answer. You can also edit someone's answer before accepting the answer.